# Running the action from a jTextField

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, text, jtextfield

I'm making the interface for a program in Java (using Netbeans) and I have a text field in which the user types commands for the program to execute. The thing is that I also have a button below the text field which should do the same thing that pressing enter after typing the command would.
So basically how do I "run" the action from the text field on a button? I just don't want to copy and paste the code all over again. I tried many of the methods from the jTextField1 object but none of those helped me. I know this may be dumb but please help me!

Comment: plz format your post. 
plz post up what you have done. plz tell us where you stuck. nobody will do your homework if it is your homework

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3):

> *"The thing is that I also have a button below the text field which should do the same thing that pressing enter after typing the command would"*

See [How to use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html).

> An [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html) can be used to separate functionality and state from a component. For example, if you have two or more components that perform the same function, consider using an Action object to implement the function. An `Action` object is an [action listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) that provides not only action-event handling, but also centralized handling of the state of action-event-firing components such as [tool bar buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html), [menu items](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html), [common buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html), and [text fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html). The state that an action can handle includes text, icon, mnemonic, enabled, and selected status.

Example:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class AddJarDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                final JTextField field = new JTextField(15);
                Action action = new AbstractAction("Hello Action"){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        System.out.println(field.getText());
                    }
                };
                field.setAction(action);
                JButton button = new JButton(action);
                JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
                panel.add(field);
                panel.add(button);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);
            }
        });
    }
}
```